# How to clear form while displaying another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two forms in my page. One's display is set to `None` while the other is set to `block` and act accordingly to two conditions. However, what I want is how to automatically clear the form in the background-the one that is set to `None`-and vice versa.

This is what I tried:

```
const firstForm = document.getElementById('first-form');
const secondForm = document.getElementById('second-form');

function clearForm() {
    if (firstForm.style.display = 'none') {
        firstForm.reset();
    }
    if (secondForm.style.display = 'none') {
        secondForm.reset();
    }
}

window.onload = clearForm;
```

But when this code runs, the First form is getting `None` as display and disappears. How do I solve this in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: First, you should probably use a variable to track what form is being displayed rather than the basing it off the elements style..also `=` != `==` In your case, they both equal `true`

Comment: Oh I completely missed the = occasion in my if statement. True that one = assigns the value. I've used == and now it works! Thank you @Ronnie